# MVC Structure. Where should be placed language folder?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, internationalization

I'm doing app using JavaFX and want to add to it different language support. Current structure is:

- app
- app.controller
- app.DA
- app.DB
- app.DB.backup
- app.model (Objects)
- app.view
- app.view.styles

Where would be right to place a language folder?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JavaFX expert but in general, language strings are a part of view model. 
So may be you can do this in app.view.model/ app.view.strings or may be in the app.model itself.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a JavaFX person. I was just answering the general standard. Let me try to find some link or code.